# Why Lie integration is called "integration"?

Tags: integration, higher-category-theory

According to [nlab on Lie integration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+integration), *The Lie integration of $\mathfrak{a}$ is essentially the simplicial object whose k-cells are the d-paths in $\mathfrak{a}$*, where $\mathfrak{a}$ is a $\infty$-Lie Algebroid. A $k$-path is an element
\begin{equation}
\Sigma \in \text{Hom}_{\infty \text{LieAlgd}}(T\Delta^k,\mathfrak{a})
\end{equation}
From which one can deduce a morphism of dg-algebras:
\begin{equation}
\Sigma^\ast \in \text{Hom}_{\text{dgAlg}}(\text{CE}(\mathfrak{a}),\Omega^\bullet(\Delta^k))
\end{equation}
where $\text{CE}(\mathfrak{a})$ is the Chevalley-Eilenberg algebra of $\mathfrak{a}$, and $\Omega^\bullet$ is the de Rham complex. Why is it called integration? What it have to do with the usual notion of integration of differential forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functor that implements the equivalence between simply connected Lie groups and Lie algebras sends a simply connected Lie group to its tangent space at the origin equipped with the appropriate Lie bracket, and a morphism of simply connected Lie groups to its derivative at the origin.

Thus, the inverse functor reconstructs morphisms of Lie groups from their derivatives at the origin, so is referred to as the integration functor.

More generally, Lie integration explains how to reconstruct
a smooth function X→G, where X is a connected smooth manifold and G is a Lie group, from its value at some point of X and its derivative (a differential 1-form on X valued in the Lie algebra of G).
A necessary and sufficient condition for this is that the Maurer–Cartan equation holds.  In this case, the original function can be uniquely reconstructed from the given data, and the process is naturally called integration,
since it generalizes the usual integration on a line.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner in higher category theory, I understand your answer on the origin of the name "integration" but I can't link what you said to the nlab entry... Can you expand your answer so I can link it to the concept involved in nlab? It would be perfect for me.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux: A Lie algebra is a special case of a Lie algebroid, which is a special case of a Lie ∞-algebroid.  The linked nLab entry describes a massive generalization of the integration procedure described in my answer to the case of Lie ∞-algebroids.  When applied to the Lie ∞-algebroid induced by an ordinary Lie algebra, it reproduces the simple case described in my answer.  You may find it beneficial to study the simple cases like this one first before moving on to the general setting.

Comment: Yes, I know that Lie algebras are special cases of Lie $\infty$-algebroids, but I wanted to know the link between your first paragraph and the "Integration to a discrete $\infty$-groupoid" section of nLab. By the notations, I suppose that $\text{exp}(\mathfrak{a})_\text{bare}$ is an $\infty$-algebroid? Sorry if my questions seem to have a trivial answer.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux: exp(a)_bare is the Lie ∞-groupoid that integrates the given Lie ∞-algebroid.  In terms of that construction, the morphism of dgas ψ:CE(a)→Ω(Δ^1) pick out a Lie-algebra-valued differential 1-form on Δ^1, which satisfies the Mauer–Cartan equation (because ψ is a morphism of dgas) and therefore integrates to a smooth path in the corresponding Lie group, which starts at the identity and whose endpoint is an element of the Lie group.  This is precisely the Duistermaat–Kolk construction of a Lie group that integrates the given Lie algebra, see the references at the nLab.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and your patience!